# Dirichlet L function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, l-functions

The function is defined here - 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function

If $\chi$ is primitive and $\chi(-1)=1$ how do I show that $L$ has infinite number of zeros in the critical strip